# Current Activity crashes while launching third party application

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to start Application **B** from Application **A** on certain action for instance a click of a button.

Now when i fire a intent from App **A** and for any reason App **B** gets crashed, it not only shows me crash dialog box but also closes my App **A**.

`launchmode` for current activity is `singleTask` and same for other app as well and care has been taken to `addFlag` of `NEW_TASK` while launching the other application.

I want a behavior in such a way that even if App **B** gets crashed i should redirect the user to the calling activity present in App **A**.

note : it is observed that when App **B** gets crashed App **A**'s activity onDestroy method is called and when it does not crash onDestroy method is not called.

Comment: Please post the logcat error trace and the code from where you are launching the third party application.

Comment: Try to post logcat & code in such case so we can help you in better way.

Comment: I am not concerned about error,wondering whether this is intended behavior.Do current activity crash if you start third party application which is crashing in oncreate of it

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods by which you can start another activity.

- If you know the package name for another application

  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().
  getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");

  if(intent != null){
  startActivity(launchIntent);
  }
- You can use implicit intents also

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  startActivity(intent);

  it will show you the apps which apps handled this intent.

  This link may helpful to you.
  [Sending user to other apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)